# Can I add the bootstrap responsive navbar into an existing site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an existing site developed using Dreamweaver's Fluid Grid system. It works fine. The one thing I would like to add is the bootstrap responsive navbar that collapses to an icon on devices smaller than a tablet. The existing menu structure is a simple horizontal spry menu bar. I've experimented with loading some of the bootstrap css and js files and trying to model the layout structure, but I'm just not doing it correctly.  Has anyone done this and have a step by step approach of what they did?
Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 0):

If navigation is the only thing that you want from Bootstrap, you can just download a customized version of the package from [Bootstrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), where you'll only select the necessary things, from the sections mentioned below:

**LESS components**

Toggle all check boxes off, then check 'Navbar', which will in turn select a few other check boxes. 'Grid system' might be necessary as well.

**jQuery plugins**

Select from `Magic` => `Collapse`, plus `Transitions` if you care about the unrolling of the collapsed menu with animation

**LESS variables**

Adjust styles from under `Navbar`, plus the variable `@grid-float-breakpoint` - which is responsible for defining the resolution at which your menu will go from full-sized to collapsed state.

**Compile** and enjoy. After the file download has started, you'll see that your URL of the customization page has changed. If you save it, you can later on open the same customization page with all fields filled in and check boxes checked.

Comment: Well I was able to download a customized bootstrap, but unfortunately I'm not able to get the structure working. I'm trying to copy the structure from here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar  but I'm obviously not doing it correctly as I get no change when reducing the browser window to mobile size.

Comment: Are you sure you've included both css and js files (in older version, also responsive js)? Also, since navbar is the only thing you want, why would you use the old BS version?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't really started working with BS3 yet and I didn't pay attention closely enough to realize that the link you gave me was for BS3 as opposed to the BS2 example I was following. I also think that the structure of my existing menu, which was generated with the Spry system in DW, needs to go as I think it will conflict with the css in BS.

Comment: Ok,getting closer. I've copied/pasted the example navbar structure, but all dropdowns display open. Also, when shrinking the browser to mobile size the navbar does change to a vertical layout with the indicator icon, but again everything is expanded and the button to contract the navigation list doesn't do anything.

Comment: Might try adding 'Dropdowns' section's CSS and JS

Comment: We're heading in the right direction. Now in desktop mode the secondary level menu items are not automatically expanded, however, the dropdowns don't work. Same thing when viewing at mobile size, the menu is collapsed now, but clicking on the icon doesn't do anything. FWIW I also included responsive utilities and animations from the components section,

Comment: Well, I had to abandon this approach. I don't think trying to add on just a specific piece of the bootstrap framework was feasible. I might have continued to experiment with which pieces needed to be compiled into the css and js files, but there would probably still be conflicts with the existing styles used in the page. In the end I found this solution (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/) which I was able to integrate into the existing design fairly quickly. In the future it would make more sense to begin with the bs framework rather than use DW's fluid grid.